# How to re-write the css class in React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stylesheet, classname

For example, I have a css class in style sheet named 'track-your-order' now on some event trigger I have to update whatever in 'track-your-order' is and apply that updated class in same div. I am not meant to toggle it but I meant to update or change or replace the same css class with new values that a user will gives it to that div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the state update and a ternary operator.

```
className={isEventTriggered? "updated-track-your-order": "track-your-order"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I'm not looking for this. This is toggling a class, I want to rewrite "track-your-order" class values, e.g., in this class values are {display:"flex, backgroundColor: '#fff'} and in props there's just values are coming like {height:"4px" width:"7px" color:"#000"} this. when this props comes it will overwrite the existing once

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use StyledWrapper from `npm` `styled-components` module.
so if you want to make 'track-your-order' become dynamic, you can simply create state that contain a new value of your css.

then put this inside your render:

```
const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  ${this.state.newStyles}
`;
```

dont forget to wrap your affected element with `<StyledWrapper></StyledWrapper>` or just wrap all of your elements inside render. for more documentation: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

edit: also dont forget to include the name of your css class inside the state. your state more or less should be look like this `.track-your-order:{display:block}`

Comment: It worked #Potamir. Bundle of thanks